# TYPO3 Extbase Dependency Injection Error/Bug in v7?

Tags: typo3, extbase, typo3-7.6.x

I am currently upgrading an extbase-extension to be TYPO3 v7 compatible,
and there is a very strange extbase behavior I simply have no clue to.

Within BackendController, A derived model has to be updated,
which looks like this:

```
/**
 * action update
 *
 * @param \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Thing $thing
 * @return void
 */
public function updateAction(\Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Thing $thing) {
    if ($this->request->hasArgument('exit')) {
        $this->redirect('list');
        exit;
    }

    $this->setFalItems($thing);
    $this->updateStuff($thing);
    $this->updateTypeModel($thing);
    //...
}

protected function updateTypeModel( \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Thing $thing ) {
    //...
    $objectManager    = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\\CMS\\Extbase\\Object\\ObjectManager');
    $mytypeRepository = $this->objectManager->get('Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\TypeWhateverRepository');
    $typeModel        = $mytypeRepository->findByUid( $TypeId );
    //...
```

in v6, `vardump( $typemodel )` showed the corresponding Object,
`Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\TypeWhatever`

in v7, `vardump( $typemodel )` is showing the parent Object,
`Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Thing`

Why is it working in v6?
Why is the exact same code not working in v7 anymore?

[dreams of dreaded bugs at night]

I digged a little bit deeper, This problem is somehow related to Dependency Injection.:

```
/**
 * typeWhateverRepository
 *
 * @var \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\TypeWhateverRepository
 * @inject
 */
protected $typeWhateverRepository;

protected function updateTypeModel(\Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Thing $thing) {
//  $typeWhateverRepository = $this->objectManager->get('Vendor\\MyExt\\Domain\\Repository\\TypeWhateverRepository');
    $typeModel = $this->typeWhateverRepository->findByUid($thing->getTypeId());

    ->  still the same problem, 
    ->   Call to undefined method Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Thing::setWhatever()
```

So, DI didn't work at all, Grmpf.
What other prerequisites are necessary to get the DI right?

(BTW, inbetween tests, i un-and reinstall the ext, clearing all caches via installtool.)

Thank you in advance.

Comment: in your last code, it must be of course $this->typeWhateverRepository instead of $typeWhateverRepository

Comment: Still no luck, the wrong model is called.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Solution to this is trivial, but was hard to find, since I was doing an Extension Update.

the extbase-typoscript setup was missing the subclasses definition m)

extbase setup is usually found in the file
`typo3conf/ext/my_ext/Configuration/TypoScript/setup.txt`:

```
config.tx_extbase.persistence.classes {
    Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\Thing {
         subclasses {
                 0 = Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\TypeWhatever
         }
    }
}
```

Also note that it is necessary for the class to have a proper 'extends' definition in the Model file.

I still wonder why it worked in v6 at all - but well, nevermind.

Answer (score 0):

First of all... lets do some clean up...

I would recommend to use the inject of your repository:

```
/**
 * seminarRepository
 *
 * @var \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\TypeWhateverRepository
 */
protected $typeWhateverRepository;

/**
 * @param \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Repository\TypeWhateverRepository $typeWhateverRepository
 */
public function injectTypeWhateverRepository(TypeWhateverRepository $typeWhateverRepository)
{
  $this->typeWhateverRepository= $typeWhateverRepository;
}
```

Then I would use an Relation from `Thing` to `Type` so you don't have to fetch these from your Repository:

```
/**
 * @lazy
 * @var \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\TypeWhatever
 */
protected $typeWhatever = null;

/**
 * @return \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\TypeWhatever $typeWhatever
 */
public function getTypeWhatever()
{
  return $this->typeWhatever;
}

/**
 * @param \Vendor\MyExt\Domain\Model\TypeWhatever $typeWhatever
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function setTypeWhatever(TypeWhatever $typeWhatever)
{
  $this->typeWhatever = $typeWhatever;
}
```

In your Thing TCA put than:

```
'type_whatever' => [
  'exclude' => 0,
  'label'   => 'LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_thing.type_whatever',
  'config'  => [
    'type'          => 'select',
    'foreign_table' => 'tx_myext_domain_model_typewhatever',
    'items'         => [

 ['LLL:EXT:my_ext/Resources/Private/Language/locallang_db.xlf:tx_myext_domain_model_thing.choose', 0],
    ],
    'minitems'      => 1,
    'maxitems'      => 1,
  ],
],
```

Comment: First of all, thank you for your quick response! The repository is injected as you described, problem persists. I have to try the relation thing now.